# How does Unity wiki's Singleton work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "manager" GameObject in my scene with a `Manager` Script component attached to it.

I need this `Manager` script to be a **singleton** since it makes no sense for there to be several managers.

I used the singleton implementation [from the Unity wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton).

I have two questions about it:

1. Why does it create a new GameObject and then use `GameObject.AddComponent<T>()` to instantiate the singleton? Why not just do `new T()`?
2. I have `protected` both of my `Singleton` and `Manager` class constructors. No one should be able to instantiate these classes except themselves. How does the Unity Editor do to instantiate them?

Comment: You cannot instantiate objects derived from Unity's internal `MonoBehaviour` class. That's why `new T()` wont work.

Comment: _I use the singleton implementation from the Unity wiki_ - it would be helpful to add the relevant parts of *your code* to your question

Comment: Note that you shouldn't define a constructor for classes that inherit from `MonoBehaviour` - use the Start()/Awake()/OnEnable() methods instead.

Comment: As for _How does the Unity Editor do to instanciate them?_, presumably via reflection. Even if a class has a `private` or `protected` constructor, you can still use reflection to find the constructor and `Invoke` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments say:

MonoBehaviour classes cannot be instanciated with `new T()` because of the way GameObject components work: they ***must*** be attached to a GameObject! As such, the GameObject class provides a way of instantiating a new MonoBehaviour attached to that GameObject: `AddComponent<T>()` which presumably operates through reflection (other MonoBehaviour methods such as `Start()` and `Update()` [aren't *exactly* invoked with reflection](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/), not every frame during runtime, but it's easy to make the comparison that they are; it's about as opaque and magical and has *significant* overhead, so it may as well be reflection).

Preventing the constructor from being called at all would probably just break everything, so don't bother trying to protect it any more than you already are.  Because of the way AddComponent works, calling the constructor through reflection, you can't actually *prevent* a new instance from being created, but you CAN detect that it happened and do something about. My preferred way is the script going "oh, an instance already exists and its not me" and destroys itself.

Additionally, as components can require other components (RigidBody requires a Collider, MonoBehaviours [can specify their own requirements](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) as well) which is specified through an attributes, when `AddComponent<T>()` is called to add the one component, it will search the class attributes to see if there are any `[RequireComponents]` specified and add them too, automatically. This would *also* be done [through reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx).